# Are Hybrid-Electric Propulsion Systems the only avenue to achieve the range and speed equivalent to current airliners?

Tags: propulsion, electric-engine

Airliners like the A320neo and 737-800 use HBP Turbofan engines to achieve cruise speeds of around 0.8 mach, and have ranges around 6,300 km. Therefore, is the only means of achieving similar numbers with more-electric focused propulsion to still utilize the HBP engines that are currently in use with electric supplementation? Or are there avenues that would no longer require combusting traditional jet fuels?

Comment: I do not believe that All-Electric or Hybrid-Electric will ***ever*** compete head-to-head with traditional jet-fueled HBP engines. Rather, electric flight will fill a different niche, enabling smaller regional flights, probably with slower, lower flight, at a price-point impossible with modern jets.

Comment: This looks like an opinion-based question because it can only be answered with large doses of speculation about heretofore undeveloped technologies.

Comment: The two big problems that electric propulsion has to solve are 1) energy density and 2) the fact that as fuel burns off, the airplane gets lighter and more efficient. 1) can be solved with some super-speculative "magic" future battery technology. 2) will never happen for batteries, so they need to be significantly more efficient than combustion engines to even just break even.

Comment: "Or are there avenues that would no longer require combusting traditional jet fuels?" – That question hints at the direction the industry is currently going: the trend is *not* towards electrical propulsion, but instead to combusting *non-traditional* jet fuels.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So something like redesigned propulsion systems that burn SAFs or hydrogen fuel could be the key towards reaching the performance we see today?

Comment: The “alternate energy propulsion system”, that might one day replace the current airliner propulsion, has yet to be invented. I think you need t look FAR outside the box for any possible replacement.

Comment: We need a crystal ball, or we can answer with opinion, which are not allowed on this site (as design)

Answer (score 2):

The premise of this question - that hybrid systems can compete with jet fuel on range in the first place - is unproven and likely incorrect.

I would however direct anyone interested in understanding the why to [a few articles](https://leehamnews.com/?s=hybrid&submit=Go) by Bjorn Ferhm, a commercial aviation analyst, who crunched the hard numbers.

- [Hybrids](https://leehamnews.com/2022/02/18/bjorns-corner-sustainable-air-transport-part-7-hybrids/), also [simplified](https://leehamnews.com/2019/06/14/30405/)
- [Serial hybrids](https://leehamnews.com/2022/02/25/bjorns-corner-sustainable-air-transport-part-8-serial-hybrids/), also [pt.1](https://leehamnews.com/2020/03/13/bjorns-corner-why-e-in-eplane-shall-stand-for-environment-part-13/)
- [Parallel hybrids](https://leehamnews.com/2022/03/04/bjorns-corner-sustainable-air-transport-part-9-parallel-hybrids/), also [pt.1](https://leehamnews.com/2020/03/20/bjorns-corner-why-e-in-eplane-shall-stand-for-environment-part-14/)

The short conclusion is that:

1. Batteries don't hold enough charge for long-range flight, and
2. There's no opportunity for regenerative braking in flight to make hybrids useful.

Electric propulsion can be useful at short range. It's perfect for training or for pleasure flights. Adding a range extender wrecks the simplicity and economy of an all-electric aircraft.

There are avenues for long-range flight that no longer require combusting traditional jet fuels. These are hydrogen and SAF ([sustainable aviation fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_biofuel#Sustainable_aviation_fuels)). Both work by burning fuel in a normal turbine engine.

Comment: I deeply deeply appreciate your answer! I also apologize for the question being a bit of a non-comparison. I supposed what I should have asked was something more akin to my last point of "without burning traditional fuels," which you aptly pinpointed at the end of your answer. So, thank you again for the info! I will be sure to take a look into the links you sent.